# Swedish Crown Molding KS. Would this be useful? Are there better tools?

Tags: tools, trim, measuring

https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/onecut/onecut-crown-molding-tool-patented-technology/description

This tools that gives a template for half the measured angle looks simple and reasonable, but does it already exist?

I've seen a video advocating a 90 degree join and coping the outline of one piece into the other. That looks really hard, but I have seen a lot of bad 45 degree joins

Opinions?

Comment: The thing that already exists looks like two rulers and where they begin to overlap/separate (depending on point of view) is the reading of the angle.  ONECUT isn't graduated in any way.

Comment: *Does it already exist?* - [yes](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Milescraft-Angle-Finder-84020113/204590192) and [yes](http://www.quality-woodworking-tools.com/tools/Nobex-Carpentry-Tools.html) and ...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it specifically requests opinions rather than asking *how* to solve a real problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coping is superior for inside corners because it's more tolerant of the trim shrinking or swelling with seasonal changes. Tools similar to that are more of a help on outside corners, which have to be mitered and are never square.

Digital protractors certainly exist, but obviously require you to divide the angle in half. The big draw of that gizmo is it does the division for you and can be put directly on the saw. The less you have to measure the better. (It also prevents you from being a bonehead and forgetting that the miter saw is marked off for roofing angles.)

It's also possible to transfer the miter angle directly with overlapping scrap blocks, eliminating the tool entirely. That rapidly gets to be less and less efficient the more outside corners you've got to deal with though. Shaving five minutes off a corner isn't a big deal when you remodel your kitchen, but it's definitely a big deal by the time you get to thirty corners.

Comment: "Tools similar to that are more of a help on outside corners, which have to be mitered and are never square."  Totally agree.  Also, the ONECUT might be more useful wherever one doesn't have 90 degree cuts to make. (ie. the deck board example).  Even if one isn't coping their inside corner molding, a 60 degree cut is better than 45.